# Create an Android library module with resources

Tags: java, android, android-studio, module, shared-libraries

I need to build an Android library, that has `JAR` dependency that represents the java code and `res` folder that includes all the drawables and different `XMLs`.

I use Android studio as my IDE.

From what I know, I need to create a module, set it as a library in the `build.gradle` file by adding `apply plugin: 'android-library'` and simply add this module as a dependency in the other module that uses it.

When I'm trying to activate my sample application with my library, I'm getting `NoClassDefFoundError` exception because he can't find one of the layouts I created.

The exact error(without the package name):

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: .R$layout
```

I tried everything by now without any success, what I forgot to do?

P.S. I know that I can use AAR, but I need it to fit with all IDEs, and from what I know Eclipse(I know Google stopped support it) and intellij doesn't support it.

Any insights will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you share your test code as git hub project? I could try to look into it. I do write such libraries and it is quite straight forward.

Comment: @Abdullah Can you give me an example, some open source describing how to do it? Thanks.

Comment: You could checkout my github project. This is a library in progress but it does what you want to do. https://github.com/abdullah-chhatra/Threepio

Comment: @Abdullah the link is not working